# How can I set custom status in discord bot according to new update?

Tags: discord.js

According to new update youu can set your own custom status without playing or listening this is't added in documentation yet what can I do here. There is no option to set custom activity in the discord.js git see the image [stable/src/util/Constants.js](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/util/Constants.js#L364) here too
[discord status image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3st5C.png)

Comment: Don't think that feature is documented already

Answer (score 9):

You can get custom status to appear on a bot, but it won't be able to say anything. According to a Github issue on discord-api-docs, [More specifically, this issue,](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/1160) and even more specifically, [this comment on that issue](https://github.com/discordapp/discord-api-docs/issues/1160#issuecomment-546549516). You can basically set the activity type to 4 for the client's cs by using the [ClientUser.setActivity()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity) method, and check it's full profile to see that custom status is technically available for bots.

```js
bot.user.setActivity(`this won't appear in the bot's custom status!`, {type: 4})
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code

```
client.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setPresence({
        status: "online",  //You can show online, idle....
        game: {
            name: "Using !help",  //The message shown
            type: "STREAMING" //PLAYING: WATCHING: LISTENING: STREAMING:
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: bro that much is in docs too need to set presence without PLAYING: WATCHING: LISTENING: STREAMING:

Answer (score 0):

Discord libaries should only be used for bots, using the API for user-account clients violates Discords [Terms of Service](https://discordapp.com/terms) as this is considered as API Abuse.
Moreover the recent announcement does not apply for bots, for many months Bots are able to set custom presence, including `listening` and `watching`.

To set this custom presence, the custom `activity`, take a look at the Discord.js Documentation [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity)

Comment: I know that but new update is yet to be implemented i saw 1 bot using custom presence see the last link of my message

Comment: I think this won't be a think for bots. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: see the last link as screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp9cn.png

Comment: Thats on a unser Account as I said

Comment: @Nerrix I'm 90% certain you're misunderstanding the question. They're saying that users can now set custom statuses, so how can bots do it.

Comment: @BrandonDyer Bot users cannot set custom statuses like users can.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Bot's custom activity, but I don't think you can add images or buttons to it.

Here's the closest thing I've got:

```js
const updatePresence = async (client, state) => {
    // Set the presence
    const activity = {
        name: 'Depression',
        type: 'STREAMING',
        details: 'discord.gg/inviteCode',
        state: state,
        timestamps: {
            start: Date.now(),
        },
     };
    client.user.setPresence({
        pid: process.pid,
        activity: activity,
        status: 'online',
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Discord does not allow you to change the custom status. This is to prevent misuse of the discord API. Please look at the [terms of service](https://discord.com/terms).

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is implemented.
Send this data to gateway and you can see a custom status.

```json
{
  "op": 3,
  "d": {
    "since": null,
    "activities": [{
      "name": "Something", // This doesn't matter
      "type": 4,
      "state": "This is custom status" // custom status value
    }],
    "status": "online",
    "afk": false
  }
}
```