# How do I set a status and Do Not Disturb at the same time? discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot Do Not Disturb and have a status.

I've searched around, and I haven't found out how to do both.

Can someone please assist me?

Comment: Do you mean like a "Playing ..." status or just words

Comment: I want the custom status to just be text, and the dot of the bot to be do not disturb.

Comment: This is not possible for bot users. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568377/how-can-i-set-custom-status-in-discord-bot-according-to-new-update

Comment: I can set the status to "listening" or "watching" then. The link is all I needed.

Comment: check my answer then

Comment: I had read that information from the link you gave me already, but yes, that answer is correct.

Comment: ya sorry there is no way to do what you want

Comment: I made my bot watching and dnd, so I got close enough to what I asked for. I'm going to stop talking because Stack Overflow doesn't like extended conversations in comments.

Comment: Yes, I've been saying that link is the answer.

Comment: I can't set the presence, but that's ok.

Comment: why are you still talking to yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set your bots activity you can do the following:

```js
client.user.setActivity('<activity>', { type: 'WATCHING' });
```

"Watching" can be changed to any of the other activity types.

[Source](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-set-my-playing-status)