# Change bot's about me in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to change my Discord bot's about me?

I'd like to setup a feature where my bot changes its about me on startup.

Basically something like this:

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setAboutMe("Hello");
})
```

Comment: ```axios.patch({url: "https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me", headers: {"authorization": token}, data: {"bio": "My Custom BIO"} )``` You can use this code snippet or, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58568377/how-can-i-set-custom-status-in-discord-bot-according-to-new-update

Comment: @dreygur I used that code and I get this error:
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object`

Comment: axios("https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me",{
  method: "PATCH",
  headers: {
    authorization: token
  },
  data: {
    bio: "My Custom BIO"
  }
})

Comment: Use the above instead

Comment: @dreygur I get the error: 400 - Bad Request

Comment: replace `token` with your auth/BOT token

Comment: @dreygur I did.

Comment: const axios = require('axios');

const token = process.env.TOKEN;

axios("https://discord.com/api/v9/users/@me",{
  method: "PATCH",
  headers: {
    authorization: token
  },
  data: {
    bio: "I'm GROOT!"
  }
}).then(({data}) => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))

Comment: This one is working on my side.